# WSDL StreamServe

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I have to use some WSDL of StreamServe Collector. The one which pissed me off a little is documentSearch.

Here is the WSDL definitions : (pastebin because it look ugly here)

https://pastebin.com/iiqB7UN7

Here is what I start to param in PHP :

```
$param = array(
        'request' => array(
            'documentTypeIds' => array(
                'current-idx' => ''
            ),
            'searchParams' => array(
                'id' => 'b46e44aa-beb8-4d0e-8f33-c1137d272214',
                'type' => '7'
            ),
            'outParams' => array(
                'id' => '',
                'type' => '15'
            )

        )
);
```

But I'm really lost about those definition and what I have to put inside. So I count on a StreamServe Collector professionnal to help me with this.

Thanks in advance